# How to get current route name in Nuxt 2 and 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js for building a static website.

How to access in component's `script` code currently displayed route name (I would like to avoid reading direct url from browser location)?

Can I somehow access `$route.name` ?

Comment: Yes you should be able to access it in component in way like `this.$route.name`

Answer (score 133, accepted):

### In Nuxt2

yes you can use vuejs route objects like `$route.name` or `$route.path`

```
$nuxt.$route.path
```

return current path

```
$nuxt.$route.name
```

The name of the current route, if it has one.

[Route Object Properties](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)

> A route object represents the state of the current active route. It
> contains parsed information of the current URL and the route records
> matched by the URL.

- $route.path
- type: string
- A string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path. e.g. "/foo/bar".
- $route.fullPath
- type: string
- The full resolved URL including query and hash.

**

> **And if you want to get the url params. Like this :
> [image]
> You do this:**

```
  data() {
    return {
       zone: this.$nuxt.$route.query.zone,
       jour: this.$nuxt.$route.query.jour
        
    }   },
```

**

Comment: My URL contains some characters after a hash sign. Not path nor name returns the value after #
/my/url/#somemore
only /my/url/ is returned

Answer (score 24):

**In Vue2**

An alternative way is to use either of the following:

- `this.$route.path` →   Example on `http://localhost:3000` ,  `{{this.$route.path}}` will print `/`
- `this.$route.name` →   Example on `http://localhost:3000`, `{{this.$route.name}}` will print `index`

Answer (score 20):

With Nuxt3 and Composition API, you can achieve that with this

```html
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
console.log('current name', route.name)
</script>
```

Or with Options API

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    console.log('current name', this.$route.name)
  },
}
</script>
```

As shown in my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72212136/8816585

Comment: For me, this doesnt work. I'm trying it in the stup, and it always says it's undefined

Comment: @CodeHacker feel free to open a new question with some relevant code.

Answer (score 6):

for Nuxt 3

```
export default ({
   setup () {
    const route = useRoute()
    return {
      route
    }
  }
})
```

after in template

```
{{ route.name }}
```

Answer (score 5):

For Nuxt 3 you can use currentRoute from router.

```
const { currentRoute } = useRouter();
const routeName = currentRoute.value.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

for Nuxt v2 [`useRouter` composition API](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/packages/routes/)

> ```js
> import { computed, defineComponent, useRoute } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
>
> export default defineComponent({
>    setup() {
>        const route = useRoute()
>        const routeName = computed(() => route.value.name)
>        return { routeName }
>    },
> })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt 3: Vue 3 and setup pattern version

```js
<script setup>
    const route = useRoute(); // built-in composable
    // route.name

    useHead( function() {
        return {
            htmlAttrs: {
                "data-route": route.name,
            },
        };
    });
</script>
```

Here's a way you can inject it.
For dynamic routes, things might be a little more tricky

Answer (score 0):

Just tried `{{ $route.name }}` in Nuxt3 and got `index`. No need for any js code.