# How to get route url params in a page in Nuxt2 and 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt.js, and have a dymanic page which is defined under

```
pages/post/_slug.vue
```

So, when I visit the page url, say, http://localhost:3000/post/hello-world, how can I read this slug parameter value inside my page.

Currently I am geting it using asyncData as follows:

```
  asyncData ({ params }) {
    // called every time before loading the component
    return {
      slug: params.slug
    }
  }
```

This is working fine, but I think this is not the best way, and there should be a better way to make the parameter available to the page. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could you tell you want use params for what?

Comment: I use this param to query and fetch some data from an API.

Comment: Then I think your way is the best way!

Comment: ok thanks! I will continue to use this method till we find a better one :)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Note: This answer is for Vue2 and Nuxt2. If you are looking for answer for nuxt3 or vue3, refer to other answers.

In the .vue file, to get the Vue router [route object](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties):

```
this.$route
```

( notice the [Vue router](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-instance-properties) is under the `this.$router` object)

The `$route` object has some useful properties:

```
{
  fullpath: string,
  params: {
    [params_name]: string
  },
  //fullpath without query
  path: string
  //all the things after ? in url
  query: {
    [query_name]: string
  }
}
```

You can use the `$route` object like this:

```
    <script>
    export default {
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.$route.fullPath);
      }
    };
    </script>
```

the url path params is under the `route.params`, as in your case `route.params.slug`

```
    <script>
    export default {
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.$route.params.slug);
      }
    };
    </script>
```

the Vue mouted hook only run on client, when you want to get the params on server, you can use the asyncData method:

```
    <script>
    export default {
        asyncData({route, params}) {
            if (process.server) {
                //use route object
                console.log(route.params.slug)
                //directly use params
                console.log(params.slug)
            }
        }
    };
    </script>
```

But, pay attention:

> It will be called server-side once (on the first request to the Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further routes.
> [ref](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/)

If you don't need the params information on server, like you don't need to get data based on the params on server side, I think the mounted hook will suffice.

Comment: params is not right, it is query

Answer (score 27):

To read params from URL you should use this way in Nuxt:

`this.$route.query.<name_of_your_parameter_in_url>`

For example

URL: `https://example.com/example/?token=QWERTYUASDFGH`

with this line of code, you can read `token`:

`this.$route.query.token`

and give you `QWERTYUASDFGH`.

Comment: query is the correct answer for me in nuxtjs

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, params != query. `example.com/post/{id}` would be a parameter, `example.com/post?id=123` would be a query.

Answer (score 10):

With the release of a stable version of Nuxt3, I feel like updating with an answer using the composition API.

This is how you would access all the interesting parts of the current route in any `.vue` file

```html
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ route }}</pre>
</template>
```

`route` getting the following in case of going to `http://localhost:5678/about?fruit=watermelon`

```json
{
  "path": "/about",
  "name": "about",
  "params": {},
  "query": {
    "fruit": "watermelon"
  },
  "hash": "",
  "fullPath": "/about?fruit=watermelon",
  "matched": [
    {
      "path": "/about",
      "name": "about",
      "meta": {},
      "props": {
        "default": false
      },
      "children": [],
      "instances": {},
      "leaveGuards": {
        "Set(0)": []
      },
      "updateGuards": {
        "Set(0)": []
      },
      "enterCallbacks": {},
      "components": {
        "default": {
          "__hmrId": "0a606064",
          "__file": "/home/kissu/code/test/n3-default/pages/about.vue"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {}
}
```

If you use the Vue devtools, you can also click on a component and find the instance via the console (helpful if you want to quickly inspect the object). It gives a bit more details than the `Routes` tab.

[image]

More info available here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-route#useroute

---

With Options API, it would be the following (as in the console)

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    console.log('route object', this.$.appContext.app.$nuxt._route.query)
  },
}
</script>
```

PS: there is maybe a shorter way that I don't know yet.

PS2: I'm always confused between `query params` and `"route params"`, hence [this memento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467277/8816585) for a difference could be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can access routing parameters

for global uses but it is not good practice:

> window.$nuxt._route.params

for local uses under pages/components/layout etc, Always we should practice like below

> this.$route

or

> this.$nuxt._route.params

Comment: This seems like a very bad practice as it's never mentioned in nuxt js documentations !

Comment: $nuxt.$route is documented though.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the store context (for example actions.js), you can access the query parameters like this:

```
this.$router.currentRoute.query['param_name']
```

Comment: This help me a lot, ty. But better use this.$router.currentRoute.params.param_name

Comment: A query params is not a path variable. Here, OP is looking for the `path variable` params as per se. Yeah, the working is poor on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are mostly enough, if you want to access route info inside `apollo` smart query:

```
  apollo: {
    items: {
      query: jobsBy,
      variables() {
        return {
          clientId: this.$route.query.id
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Declaring dynamic routes**
In nuxt2, underscore `_` was used for dynamic routes, in nuxt3, instead of
underscore `_` the dynamic routes now use the square brackets `[]`

**Accessing params**
In nuxt2, the route params can be accessed on `$route` object
e.g `this.$route.params`
In nuxt3, the params can be destructured from `useRoute` composable
e.g. `const { params } = useRoute()`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this already is the best way, if not the only one to do that. But I could suggest an slightly different approach that maybe fit to your needs. **Use the `asyncData` method to retrieve the data from the server instead of put a param at your VM and process later, if is your case.** Then, you can handle the **result** data at the presentation logic and not any kind of *request*. On the other hand, also you could use, fetch if you don't want to pass anything to the **VM** or use a **middleware** instead, according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me is :

```
async asyncData(context){
      const query_params=context.route.query;
}
```