# Dynamic Routes NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am wondering how to rename routes in nuxtjs.

In particular, I have a folder called products with an _id.vue and index.vue files. However, I do NOT want the route to be www.mysite.com/products/productID, but rather www.mysite.com/productID. That is to say, I want to remove products from the route.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Docks suggest that top-level dynamic routes will work fine](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes). Check out the `_slug` folder in the example.

So, the following folder structure works:

```
pages
--| _product/
-----| index.vue
```

And in your `index.vue` you'll have access to `product` param via `$route` object ([check this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711201/9430588)), so, it can contain something like this:

```
<!-- pages/_product/index.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center text-center py-20">
        {{ $route.params.product }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

I've tested this and it works. If having this set-up you'll go to `www.mysite.com/shampoo/` you'll see `shampoo` appearing on the screen, if you'll go to `www.mysite.com/r2-d2/` you'll see `r2-d2` and so on.

Comment: yes i have a products folder under pages folder and in that products i have index and _product files...what i would like is to remove the /products from the url and leave only the productID so that the url is like this websie/productID instead of website/products/productID

Comment: @oussemasallemi I've updated the answer with more clear explanation & an example

Comment: am sorry i tried it but it didn't pan out thank you for taking the time to think about it

Comment: @oussemasallemi Thanks for such a polite feedback! :) I've took some time to test the structure I proposed and it works. I've updated the answer to illustrate better how it could be used.