# How to change items in header based on a particular page in nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

In my nuxt app I have a header. Based on the page that I'm in, I need to change the items of header. These items are anchor links to different parts of the page. I don't want to add header to each page seperately. I want to put header in the default layout. How can I implement it?

Comment: you can use `$route.params` to detect the page you are in, and based on that show the desired link in header.  take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748575/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-nuxt-js

Comment: Suppose I have 7 pages in nuxt. I need headers specific for each of them and headers contain anchor links to different parts of that page. In your proposed method, the header will grow too big.

Comment: you can put all anchor links and titles grouped by page name  in store and get the active group based on $route, them display them in your header with a v-for

Answer (score 1):

I would use [router.js module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module) with nested routes:

```
// router.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import MyFirstPage from '~/components/my-first-page'
import MySecondPage from '~/components/my-second-page'
import MyThirdPage from '~/components/my-third-page'

import MyHeaderA from '~/components/my-header-a'
import MyHeaderB from '~/components/my-header-b'

Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        components: {
          header: MyHeaderA,
          content: MyFirstPage,
        } 
      },
      {
        path: '/b',
        components: {
          header: MyHeaderB,
          content: MySecondPage,
        } 
      },
      {
        path: '/c',
        components: {
          header: MyHeaderA,
          content: MyThirdPage,
        } 
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

```
// layout/default.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt name="header
    <nuxt name="content"></nuxt>
  </div>
</template>
```

I think this allow more control about routes and components in pages than the default nuxt router.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a solution to have a shared header. Not header for every page